# Db2 for i - RUNSQLSTM - Insert script with millions of records

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to run a big SQL script that contains millions of INSERTs to a table (for tests, I've limited it to 100,000 rows).

I've tried many different methods: CPYFRMSTMF, FTP, JDBC clients, Client Access data transfer, IBM Data Studio, SQL scripts from System i Navigator... Just to get an idea about which one of them is better.
One of those methods, is running the script (it is located on IFS) using RUNSQLSTM.

But, it takes a long, long time, just to start inserting records.
It's clear the command is doing some previous tasks, before starting to insert records.

I have selected *NONE on COMMIT parameter, as well *NOLIST in OPTION (I don't need the spool file).

But I have no idea why it takes so long time.

One incredible thing (on my tests, I've tried with 100,000 records) is running the script takes just 1min:40secs if I execute it from a software that connects iSeries using JDBC.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an example of the script?  How about the Java code?  Done right, the java code would handily beat a bunch of `INSERT INTO mytbl values (1,2,3);`  OTHO if the java code is just a bunch of `INSERT INTO mytbl values (1,2,3);`  I'd expect it to be slower.

Comment: Times are different because the query optimizer might know how to do the insert because of a previous test that you've done is in the optimizer cache.  Me I run a couple sets of tests and use the results from the last set of tests 99% of the time the last test is how the SQL will run in production.

Comment: They are common INSERT, like this:
INSERT INTO PRUMIG (ZONSDE, ZONCDE, PACSDE, PACCDE) VALUES (12345678, 12345.678, 12345678, 12345.678);
This is just an example. The real INSERT is longer. But, in this case, it works in the same way.
Before inserting records, it takes a very long time.
Remember I am speaking about millions of records (even with 100,000 I get the same result.

Comment: I've edited my answer below.  I remember now the fastest way to insert is flatfile copy.

Comment: So instead of making an insert script you would make a flat text file and copy it in.  You save all the bits for (), b

Comment: @danny117 I know, I know. I'm doing many tests about it. The difference is relly big. But, I'd need a method to insert data in CLOB columns. These columns contains just text. But, long texts. I don't know another method.
I've tries with long CHAR or VARCHAR columns, but there is record size limit for a file. And I need to upload more data than that limit.

That's why I'm trying other methods.

Comment: That's what's slowing things down.  CLOB it's cloberring you.

Comment: No, it is not just a problem with CLOB. I know it, because I've trid with other tables. Actually, my example above is really easy. It contains just numeric fields. But, if I run it using RNUSQLSTM (and million of records), it takes a long time to start.

Now I'm trying with other options: 10 or more INSERT into one sentence (look the example from @user2338816 below).
And, the best part, using shell command DB2. It's awesome!!!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to understand the situation.  Are there millions of lines of INSERT INTO... statements?  If so, then that may be the cause of a delay starting the actual insertions - actually having to read all the lines of the giant script file.

Is there one INSERT statement that does something like INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM...WHERE...?  If this is the situation then perhaps there is a delay while the optimiser does its work to read the source rows.

Something else?  Can you share a little more about the exact SQL statements in the script and the table(s) involved?

Comment: Yep, if the script is a bunch of `INSERT INTO mytbl values (1,2,3);`  that will be pretty dang slow since each line is parsed and run individually.

Comment: Yes, that's right!
SQL sentences are  'INSERT INTO PRUMIG (ZONSDE, ZONCDE, PACSDE, PACCDE) VALUES (12345678, 12345.678, 12345678, 12345.678)'

There is a big difference between running the script with 10,000 INSERT or more than 100,000. And it isn't proportional.

The table has no index, no primary key, no diary.

Answer (score 2):

If running from a script, the most likely major improvement that you can make is to use blocked INSERTs. That is, [insert many rows with each INSERT statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafyvalues.htm?lang=en).

Here are the first three INSERT statements from an inefficient script that I ran:

```
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(10, 1, 'N')
;
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(11, 1, 'Y')
;
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(11, 2, 'Y')
;
```

The full script included 100,000 INSERT statements. Two runs gave times of 20:34 and 20:32.

I ran an edit against the script to create an example of a more efficient one. I changed each statement-terminator so that four additional rows would be inserted by each statement. The first three rows then looked like this:

```
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(10, 1, 'N')                               
,(11, 1, 'Y'),(13, 1, 'N'),(14, 1, 'N'),(14, 2, 'Y');
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(11, 1, 'Y')
,(11, 1, 'Y'),(13, 1, 'N'),(14, 1, 'N'),(14, 2, 'Y');
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(11, 2, 'Y')
,(11, 1, 'Y'),(13, 1, 'N'),(14, 1, 'N'),(14, 2, 'Y');
```

I trimmed the script back so that there were only 20,000 INSERT statements (still inserting 100,000 rows, five rows at a time).

Two run times were 1:51 and 2:09, essentially a reduction of 90% in run-times for the same number of rows. If I had generated INSERTs that did 10 or 50 rows at a time, there might have been even better improvement.

The form can be seen a little better with some simple formatting:

```
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(10, 1, 'N'),
                               (11, 1, 'Y'),
                               (13, 1, 'N'),
                               (14, 1, 'N'),
                               (14, 2, 'Y');
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(11, 1, 'Y'),
                               (11, 1, 'Y'),
                               (13, 1, 'N'),
                               (14, 1, 'N'),
                               (14, 2, 'Y');
INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYDATA VALUES(11, 2, 'Y'),
                               (11, 1, 'Y'),
                               (13, 1, 'N'),
                               (14, 1, 'N'),
                               (14, 2, 'Y');
```

You might be able to automate an edit of your script to get a similar result.

Comment: Great!!
I'll try it, and I'll post my results.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For simply inserting data the fastest way is going to use an AS400 command
and flat copy the data into the file.  The fastest insert with sql is going to be a multiple insert.  Either method when you *DLY index maintenance it will go faster.

Here's how you would do a flat file copy.  This is where the data lines up in a text file exactly to the data layout of the table.  Table a is the txt file.

```
CPYF FROMFILE(A)       
     TOFILE(B)         
     MBROPT(*ADD)      
     FMTOPT(*NOCHK)
```

You can make a bulk insert go faster on the iseries by setting access path maintenance to *DLY for each logical file (index) that is based on the physical file (table).  Ignore any  warning message that the access path wasn't changed.  It's because the index is for a unique key and it can't be turned off (*DLY).  You need exclusive access to the table and indexes to use this procedure.

```
CHGLF file(myLib/myFile1) MAINT(*DLY)
CHGLF file(myLib/myFile2) MAINT(*DLY)
CHGLF file(myLib/myFile3) MAINT(*DLY)
CHGLF file(myLib/myFile4) MAINT(*DLY)
```

Do the bluk insert here.  When finished change the access path maintenance back to *IMMED for each logical file (index) based on the the physical file (table).

```
CHGLF file(myLib/myLogicalFile1) MAINT(*IMMED)
CHGLF file(myLib/myLogicalFile2) MAINT(*IMMED)
CHGLF file(myLib/myLogicalFile3) MAINT(*IMMED)
CHGLF file(myLib/myLogicalFile4) MAINT(*IMMED)
```

You can get a list of all the logical files (indexes) that are based on the physical file (table) with the DSPDBR display database relations command.

```
DSPDBR FILE(myLib/myTable)
```

Comment: The above answer is useful, but note that it is moving the elapsed time from one process (INSERT) to another (rebuild indexes).  The downside of that is the difficulty getting *EXCL access to production tables.

Comment: *EXCL sucks and Yes it moves processing.  But it's faster.  On a system with 20 indexes maybe 20 times faster.  IDK why but it's just faster for the DB to create a new index than to maintain one during the insert.  Even when you add the time for the re-indexing jobs (which by the way run automatically in a separate job so your application can continue on) the above method will finish in less time than the insert while maintaining access paths.

Comment: Your application does continue on, but every application that wants to use those logical files is going to wait until the index is completely rebuilt.  Not a problem if the only app is a batch program that prints some reports at the end of the month, but a big problem if one of those logicals is your order entry history lookup.  As with everything, it depends.  I just want the OP to have enough info to make an informed decision.

Comment: hey @BuckCalabro I said you need exclusive access for this method.  If something opens a file set to *dly it will be indexed.  It's automatic yes there will be a small delay but not like the delay you have when 20 files are being updated for each record inserted.  assuming 20 indexes.

Comment: @buck The table has no logical files, indexes, primary key, constraints, or, even, diary.
The idea is to not to loose more time than necessary, in the moment of inserting data.
So, in this case, this is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @danny117!!!
That works!!
But, instead using RUNSQLSTM I'll use shell command DB2 Utility. it is really fast, although it has some problems (error control).
[A bit more info](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahz/rzahzdb2utility.htm)

The way I use it, is really easy: 
I've created a shell batch file on IFS (QSH). Inside the file, you just need one sentence:

db2 -t -v -f $* LIB

(where LIB is the destination LIB for the Script you are running).
And, I call it using parameters, in this case, just the path to the script I want to run.

Of course, it gives you a lot of options, cause the batch file can make many different tasks.
I run everything from a CL, with STRQSH command.
This is my CLP source:

```
         DCL        VAR(&CONF1) TYPE(*CHAR) STG(*AUTO) LEN(250) +
                      VALUE('/BATCH/Batch_pruebas_migracion/bin/rundb2.s+
                      h +
                      usr/INIGREDI/PRUEBAS_MIG/PRUMIG_opt-1000000.SQL')

         CLRPFM     INIGREDI/PRUMIG


         OVRPRTF    FILE(QPRINT) OUTQ(QEZJOBLOG) MAXRCDS(*NOMAX) +
                      SPLFNAME(PRUMIG) EXPDATE(*DAYS) DAYS(7)

         STRQSH     CMD(&CONF1)
```

I'll explain the CLP a little bit more.
&CONF1 contains the command I want to execute using STRQSH. You need to write the whole path to your shell batch file.
And, in this case, then, after a blank space, the parameter. In this case, this parameter is the path to the SQL script I want to run.
I followed your advices, and that script is optimized (let me say that not always is a good idea to optimize it, it depends on the content ans size of the record you want to insert).

The 'OVRTPRTF' is done because running DB2 utility creates an spool file. It is really big, as it contains, at least, one line for every sentence into the sql script (you can change verbose mode, but minimum, 1 line).
And, to not to forget that big spool file on my system, it's programmed its authomatic deletion after 7 days.

This is really fast, specially comparing to RUNSQLSTM.
Although, FTP or CPYFRMSTMF are faster, they are a bit hard to manage with numeric fields, specially when they contains negative or decimmal numbers. (But that is another history).

And, as @danny117 told, the improvement when you optimize the SQL script, is really incredible. In some cases, I've got a difference of 2000% of speed.
It's important too, if you remove diary from your destination files. Or, of course, logical files, constraints, or whatever that implies more work for the database engine, during the transfer.

Thanks all for your help. As you can see, I've taken ideas from different answer to my question.
If you need any further explanation about how I reached my goal, don't hesitate, and ask!